# What tab key Notepad++ uses?

Tags: notepad++

After reading in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters) about tab characters I understand there are many. That is, many characters can represent a tabulation indent.

What is the character that uses for tabulation indentation in Notepad++, or at least, how could I know what is it exactly (I am very new to programming and not learning C++ and I feel searching for such data in the Notepad++ source code would now be a waste of time for me).

I need this data to write a script.

Comment: It uses the TAB character (ASCII 9).

Comment: PCMIIW, it is represented in `\s` as in `sed 's/^\s*//g'`?

Comment: `\s` is not a character.  It matches any whitespace character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press a <kbd>tab</kbd> key in NPP it adds either usual `\t` = `\0x09` character or a sequence of spaces `\0x20` according to following setting:

[image: Settings screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can view whitespace characters in Notepad++.  Select View (menu), Show Symbol, Show All Characters.  Dots are spaces (0x20).  Arrows are tabs (0x09).

[Notepad++ Regular Expressions](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) provide several special control characters to match specific text.

Specifically `\s` is not a character itself.  It matches any single whitespace character.

> **\s** 
>   A spacing character: space, EOLs and tabs count. Same as **[[:space:]]**.